# Run context.drawWindow method through a bookmarklet

Tags: firefox, canvas, bookmarklet

I want to capture a webpage as an image. I am able to do this using a firefox extension using context.drawWindow method. Now I want to strech myself and see if I can do this using a bookmarklet :)

I remember reading somewhere that context.drawWindow() works only from the firefox toolbars. I dont know if that's still true or not.

Can anyone shed some light if I can execute context.drawWindow() from a bookmarklet or no?

Thanks
Kapil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, since bookmarklets run with the permissions of the page, and drawWindow is chrome-only (can only be used by Firefox UI and extensions, not Web pages).

Comment: hmm - so i suspected. Thanks for the answer David!